# Can we create sftp proxy using apache camel?

Tags: apache, proxy, sftp

There is an application that's sending files to sftp server which was implemented by java.

To test that, we need to introduce some delay in transferring files.
Is there any way in apache camel to create a sftp proxy so that my application sends file to camel and camel send to actual sftp server with delay. without breaking any sftp mechanics.

Thanks,
Chinna

Comment: It's mentioned in their documentation that it is possible: http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html, I have found the feature request marked as implemented: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6266, they also have a test for it: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-ftp/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/remote/sftp/SftpSimpleConsumeThroughProxyTest.java. I haven't found a straight answer how to do it, yet.